# Spelling protocol (American/British/Canadian) for an International conference

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english, orthography, canadian-english

If I'm a Canadian who'll be presenting in an international conference, should I use my country's spelling, which is the Canadian/British spelling like "grey" or the more used American spelling like "gray?"

We also have our own unique spelling for some words, like "centre." I know Americans spell it "center" and I think the British spell it like the Americans.

Things to keep in mind:

- I don't know the distribution of the audience.
- The conference will be held in Germany, which isn't an English-speaking country itself.

Is there a protocol for these sort of situations?

P.S. This is a science conference, but I'm curious if a certain protocol exists.

Comment: The British spelling of centre is the same as yours.

Comment: Yeah, it's my understanding that Canadian English generally follows British spellings rather than American.

Comment: Concurring with the answers here, I'd observe that you can't please everyone, but you can always please yourself.

Comment: @karl, except where it doesn't - so we have "canadiantire centre"

Comment: @MartinBeckett - I had literally no idea what that meant. Took me a moment to realise there was a space between Canadian//Tire... That's interesting. You silly Canadians!

Comment: @karl, canadiantire is a large chain of stores in canada. But demonstrates the schizophrenic spelling

Answer (score 6):

If *you* are Canadian, then people will expect you to present using Canadian spellings. Use the system you are comfortable with.

Comment: Yeah. The important thing really is **consistency**. I am British and I teach to second language speakers so I tend to teach based on British spellings. I never mark either as incorrect though, as long as the student uses all American or all British.

Answer (score 1):

Of particular relevance is the fact that it is an **international** conference.

Your objective should be to reach out to as many of the delegates as possible with one version.

Your options in order preference would be:
1. If the conference organizers have a **style guide** of any sort, follow it by all means.
2. Else, ask if they would like to **recommend/ suggest**.
3. Failing which, follow the most widely respected and authentic **neutral references**. Avoid exclusive BrEng/ AmEng dictionaries.
4. Depending on your domain, there could be a **geographic majority**. If necessary, address it.
5. Check out all other constraints.
6. Finally, go for the version you are most comfortable and strongest in.

Answer (score 0):

Use your normal spelling.

If your content is worth listening to then nobody will care how it's spelled.

BUT - there can be issues if you use words such as grey/gray in titles, they may not show up in searches. In this Google and citation score controlled world you have to think search engine optimisation !

Comment: Good point re Google