# Non vs Non- in American Engligh

Tags: american-english

I am trying to make spelling uniform in a technical book. The book is mostly written following American conventions (say, center instead of centre, authorize instead of authorise). Should I write nonzero, nonempty, noncommutative or non-zero, non-empty, non-commutative?

Comment: Does your publisher prescribe or recommend a particular style guide? That's where I'd start. :-)

Comment: My intuition says to hyphenate *non-empty* but not the others, perhaps because *empty* is a native English word and *non* is Latinate.

Comment: If you have no idea then "non-" is generally safer.  If you think that the dash should be omitted first check if it's found in a dictionary.  ("Nonzero" is a common dictionary word.  "Nonempty" is found in some dictionaries but not others.)

Answer (score 1):

In technical writing, I prefer using "non-zero" or "non zero" as I believe it brings more clarity when reading analytical or mathematical topics.

Some other rules  -

when last letter of prefix is identical to the first letter of the following word:
anti-intellectual
non-negative
semi-independent

when there is otherwise a repeating sequence of letters that is confusing or ugly:
non-ionizing
non-oscillatory
photo-ionization
re-reading
For example, "nonoscillatory" looks like "no no scillatory" when read quickly.

when the prefix or suffix is added to a name, symbol, or number:
non-Newtonian physics
Cd-free solder
pre-1970 designs
mid-1970s

Reference: phys.uconn.edu/~eyler/phys258/W/tw.htm

Answer (score 0):

Find a style guide

I suggest you find a style guide, follow it and/or adapt it for your purposes, listing all your decisions, so you can refer to it and be consistent while editing.

If it is ‘mostly written’ using American conventions, it might be better to ‘*follow* American conventions’ instead of ‘*trying*’.

A popular guide is the ‘Chicago’ style guide.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide

Related question - ‘when to choose British or American English’:

[How to choose between British and American English for technical documents](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69401/270624)